# Run first Hadoop (on unix) program (on Windows 7)

Tags: java, unix, hadoop, virtual-machine, vmware

I have VMWare with UNIX machine running with Hadoop, on the same machine I have sample code running using Java on Windows 7. 
The code is got from here: http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/writing-a-hadoop-mapreduce-task-in-java/  
I just want to run an example of map reduce, I still didn't understand how does the program connects to the Hadoop instance, where in my code do I need to define it?

Actually, my question is how do I need to connect both? 
Is there any datasourse file that I need to update with the Hadoop credentials?

Or maybe am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For the tutorial you're using you should be running this on your Hadoop machine. If you want to run it from another machine you can but if it is Windows you will likely have trouble since the Libraries are built on Linux.

To run a job remotely you could do the following to get started. You will need to put a little effort into Job configuration.

- Install the core Hadoop Jar and libraries needed on the Windows machine. You could use a Web Application for this.
- Then build your code that will configure and call the Job. This will be straight forward with the exception of needing to set the following values in order for the Job to find the correct HDFS and Map Reducer

  conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "192.168.x.x:54311");

  conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://192.168.x.x:54310");

You will need more code than this so read up on Hadoop API [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/commands_manual.html)

EDIT: The input file should be placed on or moved into the HDFS file system that is defined within the hdfs-site.xml. If you have not formatted the HDFS file system you will need to do that first. Take a look at the HDFS user guide [HERE](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html) for more details.

Lastly, if you need additional help you will have to post the code you're trying to run and the error output as well.

Good luck,
Pat

Comment: ok, the program is now running and getting this exception: **Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/c:/input.txt,**
where do I need to put my input file?

Comment: actually my problem now is where to put my input file, any help?

Comment: I edited my answer and included a link with additional details.

Comment: I took an example from the web and I added your code, which I think that it should work fine.
My Hadoop is installed on VMWare on the same machine which took straight from Hortonworks site, installed using *.ova file.
I tried many time to install it on my local win 7 but nothing went good.
My problem is how do I put the input file in this Hadoop fs above?

Comment: The link I added in my edit has that information. You will use the Hadoop fs command with parameters. Google HDFS Shell Commands.

Comment: I can't find my Hadoop folder in this env, do you know how to find it?